# Show only the user profile of the logged in user to the logged in user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I hope somebody can help me with this. When a user logs in they se their user profile page, but if the user guesses another users profile URL they can view other peoples profiles I have tryed to use the get_object_or_404 method to restrict the access but cant tweak for user with genreric detail view. Is it possible to user get_object or do you recommend another approach?

**My user Class**

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    
    model = User
    slug_field = "pk"
    slug_url_kwarg = "pk"
```

**Get object or 404 method**

```
def user_detail(request, user_id):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, user_id=user_id, is_active=True)
        return render (request, 'users/user_detail_2.html',{'users':users})
```

Comment: You don't need a `DetailView` (simply use a `TemplateView`) to display the current user. `user` or `request.user` is inserted into the context by the builtin context processors. So you can simply write `{{ user }}` or `{{ request.user }}` to refer to the current user in the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got the question then the most easy way (as per me) is to use decorators.

Use a login decorator to allow a route only when the user is logged in.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# then at the user_detail route i.e, the route which shows the profile of a user.

@login_required(login_url='your_login_route') #'your_login_route' is the route of your login page. So if a user is not logged in, he will be redurected to 'your_login_route'
def user_detail(request, user_id):
    ...
```

**EDIT:** If you only want to show the profile to the same user and not to any other user you can try this;

```
def user_detail(request, user_id):
    if request.user.id == user_id:
        "show the profile"
    else:
        'show an error page'
```

Please make sure that the `user_id` which you are using for recognition is same as the user's id in database.

Comment: thx but its not the login that works well for me, the problem is that the user when logged in and authenticated able to se other users profile if they have the correct URL. I need the view to pass the test that if the user is logged check if the user profile belongs to the logged in user else redirect to a 404. And i need this in a generic detail view

Comment: i will edit my answer for that. please wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
@login_required
def user_detail(request, user_id):
        user = request.user
        return render (request, 'users/user_detail_2.html',{'user':user})
```

Or you can use request.user in templates, but you have to check the user is_authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    Model = User
    def get_object(self):
        """get obj here, either slug or pk"""

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user'] = self.object.filter(user=request.user)
        return context
```